# Unable to update any package on Ubuntu 20.10 because of package linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-31-generic

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates, 20.10

I have a Dell Precision 64 bit laptop and having trouble updating the packages on Ubuntu 20.10.
I have few kernels installed on my machine which I got as part of the regular updates I get from Ubuntu. But I started getting issues after an update to linux-image-5.8.0-31-generic. So I am currently using the kernel 5.8.0-29-generic. Everything works well except when I try to update any packages.
When I do `apt upgrade`, I get the following error.

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-31-generic needs to be reinstalled, but an archive for it can't be found.
```

Below are the OS details

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy


uname -a
Linux precision-3541 5.8.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 12:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I get the following when I list out all the kernels

```
╭─ ~                                                                                                                                                                     ✔  1126  19:12:21
╰─ sudo dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers'               
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1037-oem                         4.15.0-1037.42                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-28                                5.8.0-28.30                         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-28-generic                        5.8.0-28.30                         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-29                                5.8.0-29.31                         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-29-generic                        5.8.0-29.31                         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                 5.8.0.29.34                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-1037-oem                           4.15.0-1037.42                      amd64        Signed kernel image oem
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-1081-oem                           4.15.0-1081.91                      amd64        Signed kernel image oem
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-31-generic                          5.4.0-31.35                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic                          5.4.0-33.37                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic                          5.4.0-37.41                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic                          5.4.0-39.43                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic                          5.4.0-40.44                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic                          5.4.0-42.46                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-45-generic                          5.4.0-45.49                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic                          5.4.0-48.52                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic                          5.4.0-52.57                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-26-generic                          5.8.0-26.27                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-28-generic                          5.8.0-28.30                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-29-generic                          5.8.0-29.31                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iU  linux-image-5.8.0-31-generic                          5.8.0-31.33                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iU  linux-image-generic                                   5.8.0.31.36                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

I get the same error if I attempt to remove the kernel

```
╭─ ~                                                                                                                                                                   1 ↵  1122  19:10:17
╰─ sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-31-generic --verbose-versions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-31-generic needs to be reinstalled, but an archive for it can't be found.
```

I am not sure what else to try to get this fized. Can someone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend low level removal of problematic packages by using commands below:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-31-generic
sudo dpkg -P --force-all $(dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers' | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}')
```

and then remove remaining kernel packages by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

And finally install latest upgrades by

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this did not help. All worked until step sudo apt-get install byobu where I again got the error ` The package linux-modules-5.8.0-31-generic needs to be reinstalled, but an archive for it can't be found.`

Comment: I realized the error was for another package so I tried the same to remove the error package and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

sudo apt-get update

Comment: I have tried that and it did not help.